# Handing array over to function. Correct use of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I have an array/pointer related problem.
I created an int array `myArray` of size 3. Using a function I want to fill this array.
So I'm calling this function giving her the adress `&myArray` of the array.
Is the syntax correct for the function declaration`? I'm handing over the pointer to the array, so the function can fill the array elements one by one.
But somehow my array is not filled with the correct values.
In Java I could just give an array to a method and have an array returned.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myArray[3];

void getSmth(int *anArray[]);

int main(void)
{
  getSmth(&myArray);

}

void getSmth(int *anArray[])
{
  for(i=0...)
  {
    *anArray[i] = tmpVal[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove one level of indirection:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myArray[3];

void getSmth(int anArray[]);

int main(void)
{
  getSmth(myArray);

}

void getSmth(int anArray[])
{
  for(i=0...)
  {
    anArray[i] = tmpVal[i];
  }
}
```

Also, as others have suggested, it would be a good idea to pass the size of the array into `getSmth()`.

Answer (score 2):

No, the syntax is not correct. You have an extra `*`, making the argument into an array of pointers.

In general, it's better to use:

```
void getSmth(int *array, size_t length);
```

since then the function can work on data from more sources, and the length becomes available which is very handy for iterating over the data as you seem to want to be doing.

You'd then call it like so:

```
int main(void)
{
  int a[12], b[53];

  getSmth(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]);
  getSmth(b, sizeof b / sizeof b[0]);
}
```

Note the use of `sizeof` to compute (at compile-time) the number of elements. This is better than repeating the numbers from the definitions of the variables.

Comment: Note that the `sizeof` trick only works on actual arrays (`int array[]`) and not on things that have decayed to pointers (`int *array`). This means you can use sizeof to get the length after building the array but then you have to pass the length around as an extra argument.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your function accepts an `int *anArray[]` parameter, which is an **array of pointers to int**. Remove the unneccessary `*` and your function signature should look simply like this:

```
void getSmth(int anArray[]); // array of int
```

or

```
void getSmth(int *anArray);  // pointer to first array element of type int
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `int anArray[]` or `int *anArray` (which is effectively the same, because array decays to pointer). You should also make sure that the function knows how big your array is either by agreement or passing it as a parameter for it can not use `sizeof` for the purpose.